# Не удается подружить samsung pay с китайским смартфоном

Tags: android, root, samsung

Дано:

- Китайский смартфон Xiaomi
- Смарт-часы Samsung gear S3

Желаемый результат:

Хочется использовать встроенную в часы функцию бесконтактной оплаты. По заявлению производителя часов, подключить их можно к любому телефону на базе IOS/Android.

Корень зла:

Для подключения данной функции и для последующей оплаты часами необходимо установить на телефон Samsung Pay. Из магазина он не ставится с пометкой, что не поддерживается на моем девайсе. Девайс не старый, если что. При ручной установке APK из интернета получаю ошибку при установке. Плюс в приложении, которое коннектит телефон к часам должен отображаться пункт меню посвященный samsung pay. Так вот его тоже нет. Звонок в техподдержку дает ответ, почему все так. Якобы китайские телефоны с завода могут идти с рут правами или их могли накатить в магазине, если устройство приехало с китайской прошивкой для перешивки на международную. В интернете полно гайдов, как скрыть от приложений самсунга факт наличия рут прав. На сколько они рабочие не знаю, потому что рут чекер выдает сообщение, что рут прав на моем телефоне нет. Я рут не получал, с ОС и лаунчером телефона после покупки никаких махинаций не производил.

Может кто сталкивался? Или есть предполагаемое решение, кроме как рутить свой телефон, видимо, повторно.

Решение "купи нормальный телефон, нищеброд" на ум приходило, но в целом производитель и телефон сам по себе мне нравятся, а для телефонов за 100к действительно нищеброд

Comment: Это сообщество программистов, а не менеджеров по работе с телефонами. Идите в сервс по ремонту телефона и опишите проблему им.

Comment: Вроде после переустановки прошивки, root исчезает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Капитанский ответ: компания Samsung делала систему Samsung Pay не для того, чтобы кто-то пользовал ее с не Samsung телефонами. Перечень поддерживаемых телефонов можно найти на [офф сайте](https://www.samsung.com/ru/support/mobile-devices/samsung-pay-faq/).

> Samsung Pay доступен на оригинальной продукции Samsung, предназначенной для распространения на территории Российской Федерации и Республики Беларусь.

Причем кроме ограниченного количества поддерживаемых телефонов также крайне ограничен перечень поддерживаемых банков и их локализация. C таким же успехом можно пытаться использовать Apple Pay.